# Solana JSON RPC method `getLatestBlockhash` failing on localnet

Tags: web3.js, jsonrpc-api

I'm trying to call the `connection.getLatestBlockhash(...)` method in `@solana/web3.js` (version 1.50.1) on localnet but I keep encountering

```
Error: failed to get recent blockhash: Error: failed to get latest blockhash: Method not found
```

Is anyone else encountering this issue? Is this method unavailable on localnet? If it's just a problem with my local network, any known solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getLatestBlockhash` function is new in Solana version 1.9, see here: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getlatestblockhash

> NEW: This method is only available in solana-core v1.9 or newer. Please use getRecentBlockhash for solana-core v1.8

Are you on an earlier version by any chance? If you run `solana-test-validator --version` it'll tell you which version you have.

If you do have an earlier version you should be able to install the latest with `solana-install update`.